# How to pass NODE_ENV in VS Code in windows OS?

Tags: node.js, windows, visual-studio-code

I ran this and got error : `set NODE_ENV=production&&npm run server`

```
At line:1 char:24
+ set NODE_ENV=production&&npm run server
+                        ~~
The token '&&' is not a valid statement separator in this version.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidEndOfLine
```

Comment: where do you execute this code? In your command line?

Comment: vs code terminal : power shell

Answer (score 1):

If you are using VS Code terminal or Windows PowerShell(VS Code also uses PowerShell on the Windows)

```
set NODE_ENV=production; npm run server
```

and for Mac/Linux

```
NODE_ENV=production npm run server
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to run this in a script in package.json then [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env)  is a good way to set it so that it works on any OS. So that the script would be like

```
cross-env NODE_ENV=production && npm run server
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows 10 and using vs terminal. It will be work for you.

```js
set NODE_ENV=production; node server 
or 
set NODE_ENV=production node server
```

Instead of using: NODE_ENV=production node server